# set image in dynamic grid view

Tags: android

**GridActivity.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GridActivity extends Activity
{
ArrayList<String> imageurl=new ArrayList<String>();
String albumId= ConstantData.album_id;
String userId = ConstantData.user_id;
int pageNo =1;
int limit = 20;
ArrayList<Object> result;
XmlParser parser;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.photos_activity);
//Add required urls

try {
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.5.10/ijoomer_development/index.php?option=com_ijoomer&plg_name=jomsocial&pview=album&ptask=photo_paging&userid="+ ConstantData.user_id +"&sessionid="+ ConstantData.session_id +"&tmpl=component&albumid="+ ConstantData.album_id +"&pageno=1&limit=20");
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("<data><userid>" + userId + "</userid><albumid>" + albumId + "</albumid><pageno>" + pageNo +"</pageno><limit>"+ limit +"</limit></data>");
StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(strBuffer.toString());
post.setEntity(strEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

String strResponse = convertStreamToString(in);
parser = new XmlParser(in, new AddAlbumDetailBean());
result = parser.parse("data", "photo");

//Log.i("aBean Value", ""+aBean);

//System.out.println(strResponse);

String startCode = "<code>";
String endCode = "</code>";
String starPhotoCount = "<photocount>";
String endPhotoCount ="</photocount>";
String starPhotos = "<photos>";
String endPhotos ="</photos>";
String startPhoto = "<photo>";
String endPhoto = "</photo>";

String startId = "<Id>";
String endId = "</Id>";
String starTitle = "<title>";
String endTitle ="</title>";
String startThumb ="<thumb>";
String endThumb = "</thumb>";
String startUrl = "<url>";
String endUrl = "</url>";

if (startCode.equalsIgnoreCase("<code>") && endCode.equalsIgnoreCase("</code>"))
{
int startC = strResponse.indexOf(startCode);
int endC = strResponse.indexOf(endCode);

Log.i("startCode", ""+startC);
Log.i("endCode", ""+endC);

String OldCode = strResponse.substring(startC, endC);
int startCodeindex = OldCode.indexOf(">");
String code = OldCode.substring(startCodeindex + 1).trim();

Log.i("Code", ""+code);
}
if (starPhotoCount.equalsIgnoreCase("<photocount>") && endPhotoCount.equalsIgnoreCase("</photocount>"))
{
int startPC = strResponse.indexOf(starPhotoCount);
int endPC = strResponse.indexOf(endPhotoCount);

Log.i("starPhotoCount", ""+startPC);
Log.i("endPhotoCount", ""+endPC);

String OldPC = strResponse.substring(startPC, endPC);
int startPCindex = OldPC.indexOf(">");
String photocount = OldPC.substring(startPCindex + 1).trim();

Log.i("PhotoCount", ""+photocount);
}
if (starPhotos.equalsIgnoreCase("<photos>") && endPhotos.equalsIgnoreCase("</photos>"))
{
int startPs = strResponse.indexOf(starPhotos);
int endPs = strResponse.indexOf(endPhotos);

Log.i("starPhotos", ""+startPs);
Log.i("endPhotos", ""+endPs);

String OldPhotos = strResponse.substring(startPs, endPs);
int startPhotosindex = OldPhotos.indexOf(">");
String photos = OldPhotos.substring(startPhotosindex + 1).trim();
Log.i("Photos", ""+photos);
}
if (startPhoto.equalsIgnoreCase("<photo>") && endPhoto.equalsIgnoreCase("</photo>"))
{
int startP = strResponse.indexOf(startPhoto);
int endP = strResponse.indexOf(endPhoto);

Log.i("startPhoto", ""+startP);
Log.i("endPhoto", ""+endP);

String OldThumb = strResponse.substring(startP, endP);
int startUrlindex = OldThumb.indexOf(">");
String photo = OldThumb.substring(startUrlindex + 1).trim();

Log.i("Photo", ""+photo);
}
/*if (startId.equalsIgnoreCase("<id>") && endId.equalsIgnoreCase("</id>"))
{
int startI = strResponse.indexOf(startId);
int endI = strResponse.indexOf(endId);

Log.i("startId", ""+startI);
Log.i("endId", ""+endI);

String OldId = strResponse.substring(startI, endI);
int startIdindex = OldId.indexOf(">");
String id = OldId.substring(startIdindex + 1).trim();

Log.i("ID", ""+id);
}*/

if (starTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("<title>") && endTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("</title>"))
{
int startT = strResponse.indexOf(starTitle);
int endT = strResponse.indexOf(endTitle);

Log.i("startTitle", ""+startT);
Log.i("endTitle", ""+endT);

String OldTitle = strResponse.substring(startT, endT);
int startTitleindex = OldTitle.indexOf(">");
String title = OldTitle.substring(startTitleindex + 1).trim();

Log.i("Title", ""+title);
}

if (startThumb.equalsIgnoreCase("<thumb>") && endThumb.equalsIgnoreCase("</thumb>"))
{
int startTh = strResponse.indexOf(startThumb);
int endTh = strResponse.indexOf(endThumb);

Log.i("startThumb", ""+startTh);
Log.i("endThumb", ""+endTh);

String OldThumb = strResponse.substring(startTh, endTh);
int startthumbindex = OldThumb.indexOf(">");
String thumb = OldThumb.substring(startthumbindex + 1).trim();
Log.d("Thumb Url", thumb);
imageurl.add(thumb);
Log.i("Thu0mb", ""+thumb);
}

if (startUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("<url>") && endId.equalsIgnoreCase("</url>"))
{
int startU = strResponse.indexOf(startUrl);
int endU = strResponse.indexOf(endUrl);

Log.i("startUrl", ""+startU);
Log.i("endUrl", ""+endU);

String OldUrl = strResponse.substring(startU, endU);
int startUrlindex = OldUrl.indexOf(">");
String strUrl = OldUrl.substring(startUrlindex + 1).trim();

Log.i("Url", ""+strUrl);
}

}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

/*imageurl.add("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
imageurl.add("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
imageurl.add("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");*/
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent,
View v, int position, long id)
{
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context c)
{
context = c;
}
public int getCount() {
Log.i("SiZE of ImageUrl", ""+imageurl.size());
return imageurl.size();

}
public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ImageView imageView;
if (convertView == null) {
imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
} else {
imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}

/*AddAlbumDetailBean aBean = (AddAlbumDetailBean)result.get(position);
imageurl.add(aBean.thumb);*/
String strURL=imageurl.get(position);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;
URL url;
try {
url = new URL(strURL);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
in=conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bitmap1= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}



//imageView.setImageResource(imagen]);
return imageView;
}
}
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream in)
throws IOException {


if (in != null) {
Writer writer = new StringWriter();

char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try {
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
int n;
while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
} finally {
// in.close();
}
return writer.toString();
} else { 
return "";
}
}
}
```

**XMLParser.java**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class XmlParser extends DefaultHandler{

public String RootElement;
public String RecordElement;
public InputStream in;
public Object mainObj;  
public Object newObj;
public boolean inProcess;
public String xmlURL;

public ArrayList<Object> Records = null;

private final String TAG = "XmlParser";

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); 
String elementName;
String elementValue;

public XmlParser(InputStream is,Object tempObj)
{
in = is;
mainObj = tempObj;  
Log.i("Object value", ""+mainObj);
inProcess = false;
}



public XmlParser(String strURL,Object tempObj)
{
xmlURL = strURL;
mainObj = tempObj;  
inProcess = false;
}

public ArrayList<Object> ParseUrl(String rootElement ,String recordElement)
{
RootElement = rootElement;
Log.i("RootElement",RootElement);
RecordElement = recordElement;
Log.i("RecordElement", RecordElement);

try
{
URL sourceUrl = new URL(xmlURL);
Log.d("URl", xmlURL);
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
reader.setContentHandler(this);

reader.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}

return this.Records;
}



public ArrayList<Object> parse(String rootElement, String recordElement)
{
RootElement = rootElement;
RecordElement = recordElement;
Log.i("Root Element", ""+RootElement);
Log.i("Record Element", ""+RecordElement);
try{
SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
parser.parse(in, this);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
return this.Records;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String Uri, String localName,String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
{
Log.d("URl", xmlURL);
elementValue = "";
Log.i("IN STARTELEMENT", ""+elementValue);
if(localName.length() > 0)
{
Log.i("Local Name Length", ""+localName.length());
Log.i("LocalName", ""+localName);
if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RootElement))
{
Records = new ArrayList<Object>();
Log.i("Root element", ""+RootElement);
Log.i("Records", ""+Records);
}
else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RecordElement))
{
newObj = ClassUtils.newObject(mainObj);
Log.i("Main Object", ""+mainObj);
Log.i("Record element", ""+RecordElement);
ClassUtils.objectMapping(newObj, localName, elementValue);
Log.i("Element Value", ""+elementValue);
inProcess = true;
}
}
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch,int start,int length) throws SAXException{
elementValue+= new String(ch,start,length).trim();  
Log.i("CHARACTERS VALUE", ""+elementValue);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String Uri,String localName,String qName) throws SAXException
{
if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RecordElement)){
Records.add(newObj);
inProcess = false;
}
else if(inProcess){ 
ClassUtils.objectMapping(newObj, localName, elementValue);  
}
}   
}
```

**AddAlbumDetailActivity.java**

```
import android.util.Log;

public class AddAlbumDetailBean
{
public String data = null;
public String code = null;
public String photocount = null;
public String id = null;
public String title = null;
public String thumb = null;
public String url = null;

public AddAlbumDetailBean()
{
this("","","","","","","");
}

public AddAlbumDetailBean(String data,String code,String photocount,String id,String title,String thumb,String url)
{
this.data = data;
this.code = code;
this.photocount = photocount;
this.id = id;
this.title = title;
this.thumb = thumb;
this.url = url;
}

}
```

Comment: trying to set images in dynamic grid view but getting only last image.please help me.

Comment: Man! this is exhaustive. Do you think everyone will be having a lot of time to read through this code? and please format your question nicely so that the code in your question appears nice.

Comment: and please use things like http://gist.github.com or pastie.org to post this much code, for this is not a "show me the code" site. you should be here to get the concepts (or call them algorithms) and implement it yourself

Answer (score 0):

While using grid view it is not easy to Set the Image View. but you can do it by trick.
Take Button instead of the Image and set the Button Background for the Appropriate image.
After that u can able to set the Set the Button in grid view.
Thanks.

Comment: my friend through this code i am able to set image but getting last image i want to set all images....rather than last one